# Can class number $h(d)$ equal to zero for some $d$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

We know that $L(1, \chi)$ is related to the class number $h(d)$ with a constant. And this is one way that we can prove $L(1, \chi)$ not vanish on $s = 1$.

What confused me is: we know that class number $h(d)$ is zero for some $d$. (in other words, not every $h(d) > 0$).

Will this imply that $L(1, \chi)$ vanish sometimes?

Comment: "we know that class number h(d) is zero for some d. " Which $d$ would that be? Even if the extension is trivial the class number is $1$.

Comment: My confusion is from quadratic form. Because for some number d, for example, d = 5 or d = 9, the number of reduced forms with discriminant equal to -5 or -9 is ZERO.  My understanding is that the number of reduced forms with discriminant -d is just class number h(d).  Is this understanding wrong ?

Comment: In other word, not every number d can be a discriminant. If -5 can not be a discriminant, what will be class number of L function L ( 1 , χ )  for Xd where d = 5 ?

Comment: "the number of reduced forms with discriminant equal to -5 or -9 is ZERO.  "Are you sure?

Comment: Should be, right ? Can you find a quadratic form whose discriminant equal to -5 ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Xd where d=5"?  The quadratic Dirichlet character of conductor 5 corresponds to the forms of discriminant 5, not discriminant -5.  If you want to consider the field $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{-5})$, the corresponding Dirichlet character has conductor 20, and there are indeed forms with that discriminant.

Answer (score 4):

The class number $h(d)$ is defined as the cardinality of the class group of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$. Often one restricts to squarefree $d$, among others as squares can just be discarded anyway getting the same field.

For $d<0$ (and $d$ squarefree) this is the same as the number of classes of integral binary quadratic forms with discriminant equal to the **discriminant** of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ which is $4d$ or $d$ depending on a congruence condition modulo $4$. (For $d>0$ there is also a relation, but it is more subtle. But still the discriminant of the field is relevant.)

The class group is, as the name suggests a group and hence never empty. Thus its cardinality is always at least $1$.

Note that when the ring of integers is a principal ideal domain it is $1$ (all ideals are principal, so there is one class, that of the principal ideals), even in the "worst case" that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]= \mathbb{Q}$, it is still $1$. The ring of integers are the (rational) integers, but that's fine, they are as good as any PID for that purpose.

Comment: I do not think we can find a discriminant equal to -5, so what is the class number of h(5) ?

Comment: I am not sure why you mix the signs. According to my explanation $h(-5)$ is the cardinality of the class group of $Q(\sqrt{-5})$ this has discrimiant $-20$  (and not $-5$) so what is relevant are the form with discrimant $-20$, and there are two classes. But I now think I understand the root cause why we are talking sideways. I'll update my answer in a bit.